# How to check if a Firefox add-on is malicious?

Tags: firefox, browser-extensions, malware-analysis

How to check if a Firefox add-on is malicious ?

I'm interested about this one currently : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/istilldontcareaboutcookies/

It got a Github repo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find malware in browser extensions](/questions/15726/), [How to test if a browser add-on is safe](/questions/8934/), [How do I check the code of a Chrome extension to make sure it's not stealing my info?](/questions/10962), [Any tool for scanning vulnerabilities in browser extensions?](/questions/33834), [How to defend myself against potential malicious browser add-ons?](/questions/206349).

Comment: thank you very much